# MVC Routing not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get to grips with the MVC Routing system but its not working as I would expect.

Say I have this route defined:

```
context.MapRoute(
        "NewCertificates",
        "NewQuote/GetCertificate/{date}/{id}",
        new { area = "NewQuote", controller = "Quote", action = "GetCertificate" },
        new[] { "Acme.Areas.NewQuote.Controllers" }
    );
```

And this Action Link in my View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "GetCertificate", new { controller = "Quote", area = "NewQuote", date = "20121219", id = "acme" })
```

I'd expect the generated URL to look like:

```
http://localhost:50582/NewQuote/GetCertificate/20121219/acme
```

but instead I get:

```
http://localhost:50582/NewQuote/GetCertificate/acme?date=20121219
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Edit to show routes which precede the one mentioned above:

```
        context.MapRoute(
                "NewQuoteValidation",
                "NewQuote/Validation/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "NewQuote", controller = "Validation", action = "IsImeiAvailable", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Acme.Areas.NewQuote.Controllers" }
            );

        context.MapRoute(
                "NewAjax",
                "NewQuote/Ajax/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "NewQuote", controller = "Ajax", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Acme.Areas.NewQuote.Controllers" }
            );

        context.MapRoute(
                "NewQuote",
                "NewQuote/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "NewQuote", controller = "Quote", action = "Select", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Acme.Areas.NewQuote.Controllers" }
            );
```

Comment: Can you include the other routes you have defined, and their order?   It may be that the link is getting constructed based on another route definition.

Comment: @FloatLeft, just make sure that if you have any other routes that are similar to have the more restrictive ones first, then have the more general ones.

Comment: hi dbaseman. Have added the preceding routes to the end of the question. Youre right though, the 'NewCertificates' route is declared last

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that another, prior route definition is claiming ownership of the `ActionLink` definition.  You might want to try:

1. Putting the "NewCertificates" route definition first, or higher in the list.
2. Constructing the link explicitly based on the route, using `Html.RouteLink`

---

```
@Html.RouteLink("Click Here", 
      // route name
    "NewCertificates", 
      // route attributes
    new { controller = "Quote", area = "NewQuote", date = "20121219", id = "acme" })
```

Comment: The 'NewCertificates' was the last route defined. I've edited the question to show the preceding routes. I guess the URL is being constructed from one of those but how can you tell which one?

Comment: Use the Route Debugger, Luke! http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this for calling your Route:

@Html.RouteLink("Click Here", "NewCertificates", new { controller = "Quote", area = "NewQuote", id = "acme" })